# Map though an object inside a single array using JSX

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, use-state

So I have this single object which has a nested list of object which is "loans"

```
{
    "cid": 1,
    "fname": "test fnamne",
    "mname": "test mname",
    "lname": "test lane",
    "address": "test address",
    "gender": "Male",
    "sourceOfFund": "work",
    "coMaker": null,
    "contactNumber": "09382853287432",
    "loans": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "location": 1,
            "area": 100,
            "pricePerArea": 4000,
            "interest": 16,
            "term": 24,
            "downPayment": 20000,
            "dppurpose": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

how can I effectively map through the loans object using jsx code in react?
I currently have this code:

```
  function DataFetching() {

    const [customer, setCustomer] = useState({})
    const [id, setId] = useState(1)
    const [idFromButtonClick, setIdFromButtonClick] = useState(1)

    const handleClick = () => {
        setIdFromButtonClick(id)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        axios 
            .post(`http://localhost:9090/api/customer/getCustomerByCid`,{cid:idFromButtonClick})
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                setCustomer(res.data)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }, [idFromButtonClick])
    return (
        <div>
            <input type='text' value={id} onChange={e => setId(e.target.value)}/>
            <button type='button' onClick={handleClick}>Fetch Post</button> <br></br><br></br>
            
           { customer.loans.map(item => (<li key={item.id}>{item.area}</li>))}
           
        </div>
    )
}
```

which is giving me an error of  "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this approach -->> `{ (customer?.loans || []).map(item => (<li key={item.id}>{item.area}</li>))}`

Answer (score 1):

Set a default value in case `loans` are not present in the object before the iteration.

```
{ (customer?.loans || []).map(item => (<li key={item.id}>{item.area}</li>))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is essentially correct, however there's a logic flaw - within the first components render, `customer` will equal the default value you set (`{}`).

In that case, `customer.loans` does not exist, as `customer` is an empty object.

I'd suggest setting the default value of `customer` to `null`:

```
const [customer, setCustomer] = useState(null);
```

Then later in your code, check whether the customer has already been fetched - in case it hasn't, perhaps display a loading spinner.

So all in all:

```
function DataFetching() {
  const [customer, setCustomer] = useState(null);
  // ...

  useEffect(() => {
    // ... fetch data
  }, [idFromButtonClick]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={id} onChange={(e) => setId(e.target.value)} />
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Fetch Post
      </button>
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      {customer === null ? 'Loading...' : customer.loans.map((item) => (
        <li key={item.id}>{item.area}</li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially `loans` and `customer` is undefined thats why this error is showing

`"Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"`

Try this code:

```
{ customer?.loans?.map(item => (<li key={item.id}>{item?.area}</li>))}
```

or

```
{ customer?.loans?.length > 0 ? 
(customer.loans.map(item => (<li key={item.id}>{item.area}</li>)))
: undefined}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save this array in other state:

```
    function DataFetching() {
  const [customer, setCustomer] = useState({})
  const [id, setId] = useState(1)
  const [idFromButtonClick, setIdFromButtonClick] = useState(1)
  const [loans, setLoans] = useState([])

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIdFromButtonClick(id)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post(`http://localhost:9090/api/customer/getCustomerByCid`, {
        cid: idFromButtonClick,
      })
      .then(({data}) => {
        console.log(res)
        const loans = data.loans ? data.loans : [];
        setCustomer(data)
        setLoans(loans)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }, [idFromButtonClick])
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={id} onChange={e => setId(e.target.value)} />
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Fetch Post
      </button>{' '}
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      {loans.map(item => (
        <li key={item.id}>{item.area}</li>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Or can use this code for map items:

```
{customer.loans &&
    customer.loans.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.area}</li>)}
```